# remix-desktop BUG :White Screen on Remix Desktop IDE

Tags: bug

[image]

White Screen on Remix Desktop IDE

---

[image]

The mistake changed again   。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。

Comment: Did you try to delete cookie and refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

change the url to
"https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/version.json"

or just paste this function in the console

```
fetch('https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/version.json', { cache: "no-store" }).then(response => {
  response.text().then(function (data) {
    const version = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(`Loading Remix ${version.version}`);
    createScriptTag(`polyfills.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
    if (version.mode === 'development') {
      createScriptTag(`vendor.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
      createScriptTag(`runtime.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
    }
    createScriptTag(`main.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'text/javascript');
  });
});
```